# How to use IF method to change one text to another if the text has double quotes (" ")

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example, I use this method:

```
=IF(A2="A","B","")
```

but if the text "`A`" is for example `GOODLE "2A"` the formula does not work.

Comment: Are different text but which have "" like Goode "2a" or "Eman" AB

Comment: The problem is with the double quotation "". With texts that have not "" i have no problems but with these text like Goode "2a" the formul is not correct.

Comment: A B
1  GOODLE "2A"
2  GENER "3C"
3  Grand "2B" AA

Comment: Instead of giving hypotheticals, please provide an example of actual data you want to run this on, including your expected results. It is not clear right now what you mean by this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the second and next double quotes. The conventional escape character is ... a double quote so:

```
=IF(A2="GOODLE ""2A""","B","")
```

should work. An alternative is judiciously to concatenate with CHAR(34) in place of some of the double quotes but in terms of the logic of what is happening that does not seem to help.